# Como armazenar vários valores lidos do usuário?

Tags: python

```
aluno = int(input('Qual o numero de alunos ? '))
for i in range(aluno):
    nota = float(input('Insira a nota de cada um dos alunos: '))
```

Preciso saber como armazeno as notas dos alunos para somar e dividir pela quantidade de alunos digitados no programa

Comment: Já conhece a estrutura [lista](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) do Python?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar uma [lista](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

```
notas = []
aluno = int(input('Qual o numero de alunos ? '))
for i in range(aluno):
    nota = float(input('Insira a nota de cada um dos alunos: '))
    notas.append(nota)
```

E para calcular a média, basta calcular a soma, `sum()`, e dividir pelo número de notas, `len()`:

```
media = sum(notas) / len(notas)  # Pode ser "aluno" no lugar do "len"
```

Ou utilizar o pacote [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html):

```
from statistics import mean

media = mean(notas)
```

Veja o [código funcionando](https://ValuableLovingBackticks.acwoss.repl.run).